# VB.NET RaiseEvent in thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, events

When I raise an event in my thread, the thread is no longer running in the loop.

```
Public Sub readStream()
    Dim netStream As NetworkStream = Me.client.GetStream()
    Do
        Try
            Dim inStream As Byte() = New Byte(20000) {}

            netStream.Read(inStream, 0, CInt(Me.client.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Console.WriteLine("Received something")
            RaiseEvent rsh(Me, New ReceiveStreamEvent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)))
            Console.WriteLine("I am still alive")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("ReadStream Error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can see that "I am still alive" never occurs.. I did the same code in C#, I don't have this issue with it. So when RaiseEvent is called, the thread will not continue. I have no errors, no messages.

Here is the complete class:

```
 Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Delegate Sub ReceiveStreamHandler(source As Object, e As ReceiveStreamEvent)

Public Class ReceiveStreamEvent
    Inherits EventArgs
    Private stream As String
    Public Sub New(stream As String)
        Me.stream = stream
    End Sub
    Public Function getStream() As String
        Return Me.stream
    End Function
End Class

Public Class server
    Private client As TcpClient
    Private readThread As Thread
    Public Event rsh As ReceiveStreamHandler


     Public Sub New()
        Try
            Me.client = New TcpClient("172.16.26.56", 8000)
            Me.readThread = New Thread(AddressOf readStream)
            Me.readThread.Start()
            Me.readThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("TCP conn error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub disconnect()
        Try
            Me.readThread.Abort()
            Me.client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("TCP disc error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub readStream()
        Dim netStream As NetworkStream = Me.client.GetStream()
        Do
            Try
                Dim inStream As Byte() = New Byte(20000) {}

                netStream.Read(inStream, 0, CInt(Me.client.ReceiveBufferSize))
                Console.WriteLine("Received something")
                RaiseEvent rsh(Me, New ReceiveStreamEvent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)))
                Console.WriteLine("I am still alive")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("ReadStream Error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
            End Try
            '  Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Sub writeStream(message As String)
        Dim netStream As NetworkStream = Me.client.GetStream()
        Dim outStream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)
        netStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
        netStream.Flush()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you ensured that port forwarding is enabled on your router? Have you ensured that port isn't blocked in windows firewall. Also, if you are handling the event you are raising from a different thread, you would get a illegal crossthread error, I suggest adding a "Parent As Control" property to your server, that way you can raise a private event that will later invoke on the parent thread to raise a public event(that the parent thread can handle).

Answer (score 0):

It is more a resolution than an answer but the code below shows my sub handling the event. When using Console.WriteLine on e.getStream() it showed once a result then the rest of the code was never seeked nor the thread. I've putted it in comments, and now everything works correctly. Even if I use e.getStream() somewhere else it works. This is the kind of situation that really make me mad with VB.NET and even if C# is slightly the "same" it is clearer and much more comprehensible. I still have no answer for this consuming Console.WriteLine and would be glad if some friends here could take a thinking about it. Cause it's very obscure wakadudle thing around here.

```
 Private Sub receiveData(source As Object, e As ReceiveStreamEvent) Handles apiServer.rsh
        Try
            ' Me.richTextBox_DATA.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() Me.richTextBox_DATA.Text = Me.richTextBox_DATA.Text + e.getStream()))
            '       Console.WriteLine(e.getStream())

            Dim list As String() = e.getStream().Split(New String() {vbLf, vbCr & vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            For Each str As String In list
                If str.StartsWith("RESP") Then
                    Me.parseResp(str)
                End If
                If str.StartsWith("LOGOUT") Then
                    Me.parseLogout(str)
                End If
                If str.StartsWith("LOGIN") Then
                    Me.parseLogin(str)
                End If
                If str.StartsWith("GPS") Then
                    Console.WriteLine("GPSGPS")
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```